# Why Does An App.config For A Console App Contains {}

Tags: .net, app-config, curly-braces

```
<!-- Server Parameters-->
<add key="DatabaseServerName" value="MySqlServer"/>

<!-- Data Access Parameters-->
<add key="DataAccessConnectionString" value="server='{DATABASESERVERNAME}';uid='UserName';pwd=password;database='Database1';Trusted_Connection=Yes;initial catalog='Database1';Async=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"/>
```

I could not find anything about this here or on Google. I have a VB.Net console app that I have inherited that has tis in the app.config and I cannot figure out why it is there nor what it is supposed to do. The {DATABASESERVERNAME} is confusing to me. It seems to work fine in prod, but it is failing when I try to use it in dev. I am guessing that it some kind of parameter reference to the value in the DatabaseServerName key, but I do not understand why it just doesn't work when I try to run this. The DataAccessConnectionString just comes back with server='{DATABASESERVERNAME}';uid='UserName';pwd=password;database='Database1';Trusted_Connection=Yes;initial catalog='Database1';Async=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=true

Anyone know anything about this convention?

Thanks

Comment: It is probably replaced with the actual server name in code somewhere.

Comment: No, it isn't. That is part of what is confusing me.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Are there different App.config files for Debug and Release? Why not post the code that is reading `DataAccessConnectionString`? Is it also reading `DatabaseServerName`?

Comment: That looks like a transform; typically used by web publishing. If this is a console app, how are you deploying it? NuGet? Azure? WIX?

Comment: I finally found it. It was buried down inside a nested set of functions while loading the configuration. Steve had it right.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it. It is being swapped out in the code. It was buried down inside a nested set of functions while loading the configuration. Steve had it right.

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).